# ionic4/Angular7 - Property 'dataDirectory' does not exist on type 'File'

Tags: download, native, ionic4, cordova-native-file

i user [file transfer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/) for download file that it's need [File native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file) also
in **ionic v3** i used it and hasn't any problem but now in  **ionic v4** when i use that, it's got Error : Property 'dataDirectory' does not exist on type 'File'

my code => **download.page.ts**

```
download() {
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      const url = 'http://www.test.com/file.mp3';
      fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.mp3').then((entry) => {
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
      }, (error) => {
        // handle error
        console.log('download EROR: ' + error);
      });
    });
  }
```

File imported in download page and providers app module

Comment: Can you show us your import routes for File and File Transfer? Ionic 4 uses slightly different import paths (with /ngx at the end)

Comment: Really Thanks, by addign  /ngx solved. Thank you @Tomas-Vancoillie

Comment: No problem! I've added a real answer so you can accept and close the question ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ionic 4 uses different import paths in compairson to Ionic 3.

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
```

Comment: this is correct but please update the second line so it is: import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

Comment: Suddenly having this issue after being working for months on a project, I don't know what  happened.. I have the right imports for ionic 4 and everything was working fine until today.. I got this error with other similar errors: 'Property 'applicationDirectory' does not exist on type 'File'' I Have the import as 'import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx' but no luck.... any idea how to fix the problem i'm having?