# Property 'dataDirectory' does not exist on type 'File'

Tags: ionic4

I'm trying to use the FileTransfer [Ionic 4 example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer).

I've performed the installation steps:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install @ionic-native/file
```

I've created a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DownloadService {

  fileTransfer: FileTransferObject;

  constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File) {
    this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
  }

  download(url: string, destFileName: string) {
    this.fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + destFileName).then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('download failed' + error);
    });
  }
}
```

However, this results in compilation error:

> ERROR in src/app/services/download.service.ts(20,47): error TS2339: Property 'dataDirectory' does not exist on type 'File'.

I've seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530955/ionic4-angular7-property-datadirectory-does-not-exist-on-type-file).  However, I'm importing correctly as suggested by the accepted answer, so I believe this question is different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this :

```js
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
```

When using Ionic4, you have to add `/ngx` to every `@ionic-native` imports. Basically, it provides an Ionic4 dedicated typing.